# How to get all columns using Distinct on oneColumn and Union on tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct, union

I am using following query to get Count of Unique Records from a table based on 3 conditions as below:

```
Select COUNT(*) FROM (   select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL) from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999'  
    Union   
select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL) from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901'  
    Union   
select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL) from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'  
) Counts
```

Now What i want is : i want to get all the data of these records..

i have tried

```
 Select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL), SUBSCRIBER_Id FROM  (select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999'
  Union    
 select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901'    
  Union 
 select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'    
 ) x
```

but using this i am getting all the records, means distinct is not working in this case.

please help me how can get distinct email addresses with other data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do the distinct like this:

```
SELECT distinct * from
(
  Select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL), SUBSCRIBER_Id FROM  (select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999'
  Union    
 select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901'    
  Union 
 select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'    
)
```

Comment: are you getting any error or it is just returning not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First query can be this:

```
Select COUNT(*) FROM (   
select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL) 
from SUBSCRIBER 
where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  
and (SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'   
    OR SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999' 
    OR SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901')
) Counts
```

Second... if you want all data:

```
SELECT S.*
FROM SUBSCRIBER S
JOIN (   
select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL) 
from SUBSCRIBER 
where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  
and (SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'   
    OR SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999' 
    OR SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901')
) Counts
ON S.SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL = Counts.SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL
```